# Why radiant heat only travels as infra-red waves and not as other types of em waves like UV rays

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation

Heat is a form of energy and em waves carry energy as momentum of photons. So, I think, radiant heat can travel at any frequency.

Please correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Thermal radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation) consists of [electromagnetic radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) that was produced by the thermal motion of charged particles in matter.  In particular, the thermal radiation surrounding an object in [thermodynamic equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_equilibrium) with its environment is known as [black-body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation), which has a characteristic spectrum that depends only on the object's temperature.

Most of the thermal radiation emitted by objects at room temperature is [infrared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared), but some thermal radiation outside of the infrared range is emitted, as well. Hotter objects emit thermal radiation with a shorter peak wavelength.   For example, sunlight is thermal radiation that includes a substantial amount of radiation in the [ultraviolet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet) range, which involves wavelengths that are shorter than infrared.  As an example in the other direction, the [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) is thermal radiation that peaks in the [microwave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave) range of wavelengths, which involves wavelengths that are longer than infrared.

So you are correct to say that thermal radiation doesn't consist only of infrared radiation.

Answer (score 1):

The (say, average) frequency depends on the temperature of the body emitting the thermal radiation. It's infrared for room temperature, it can be UV for much higher temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

Might find this useful
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Black_body.svg
Shows the dominant wavelength that black bodies emit EM waves at. Notice that I said dominant, doesn't mean that it's the only wavelength they emit at, just the one that is emitted the most on average.

Might find this a good read too.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation